# Swift - Keeping tab bar displayed through out project

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have seen many other questions very close to this one but couldn't find a solution for this precise case :

I have a tab-bar application, connected to 4 `UIViewControllers`. I'm trying to connect one of these 4 `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController` using a Show action segue and keeping my tab bar displayed.

I'm not embedding the 4 first `UIViewControllers` in `UINavigationController`.
Simulated metrics are set to inferred and "Hide bottom bar on push" is unchecked. Segue kind is set to "Show (e.g. Push)".

On my storyboard, the tab bar automatically appears at the bottom of the last created view when I add the segue. When building the project, the tab bar is visible only on the 4 `UIViewControllers` directly linked to the `TabBarController`. However, I lose it when the last view is showed.

How do I keep my tab bar displayed on this last view ?

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Found this simple solution :

I have embedded the first ViewController in a Navigation Controller. As I didn't want to show a navigation bar in my header, I simply hid it in Viewdidload :

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
```

Hope this will help someone !